# Select max date from sql server table saved as varchar data in "mm-yyyy" format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In a table date data is saved as **mm-yyyy** format and its datatype is varchar.

Now I want to retrieve `MAX` date.

Date is saved in below format and there are thousands of records:

```
7-1986
10-2012
6-1989
5-1975
7-1974
7-1961
12-1987
10-1975
6-1959
10-2002
12-1991
11-1961
6-1966
12-1959
10-1956
12-1953
6-1999
2-1989
```

I tried:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, '1-'+[Date], 105)) As MAXDate FROM tablename
```

But it returns `2015-12-01 00:00:00.000`, but it should be `2015-01-01 00:00:00.000` , because `MAX` date is saved as `1-2015`.

Comment: Is there any way at all that you could change your table? Ideally, use a proper date field (just record the 1st of each month) but at least use yyyy-MM.

Comment: Actually there are millions of record (25 million), I can't change format.

Comment: The number of records rarely affects how feasible it is to change them - it would be more about the amount of other code (and systems that have to keep running) that would affect that. Again, if you can *possibly* make this saner, it will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try.

```
SELECT Max(cast('1-'+Date as DateTime)) As MAXDate FROM tablename
```

Comment: Sorry getting error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Once try updated answer. you are using only month year . so now i append '1-'

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(Datestring, 4) + RIGHT('00' + SUBSTRING(DateString, 1, CHARINDEX('-', DateString, 1) - 1), 2) + '01' AS SMALLDATETIME)) FROM [YourTable]
```

SAMPLE:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates(DateString  VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES
('7-1986'), ('10-2012'), ('6-1989'),
('5-1975'), ('7-1974'), ('7-1961'),
('12-1987'), ('10-1975'), ('6-1959'),
('10-2002'), ('12-1991'), ('11-1961'),
('6-1966'),  ('12-1959'), ('10-1956'),
('12-1953'),  ('6-1999'), ('2-1989');

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        DateString,
        [Month] = SUBSTRING(DateString, 1, CHARINDEX('-', DateString, 1) - 1),
        [Year] = RIGHT(Datestring, 4),
        [Date] = CAST(RIGHT(Datestring, 4) + RIGHT('00' + SUBSTRING(DateString, 1, CHARINDEX('-', DateString, 1) - 1), 2) + '01' AS SMALLDATETIME)  
    FROM #Dates
)
SELECT MAX([Date]) AS MaxDate FROM CTE
```

**DATA**

```
DateString
----------
7-1986
10-2012
6-1989
5-1975
7-1974
7-1961
12-1987
10-1975
6-1959
10-2002
12-1991
11-1961
6-1966
12-1959
10-1956
12-1953
6-1999
2-1989
```

**RESULT**

```
MaxDate
-----------------------
2012-10-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STUFF` function to add `-1`:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]), 0, '-1'), 121))
```

Comment: Sorry its still giving wrong answer "2015-12-01 00:00:00.000".

Comment: @AnandMeena: Are you absolutely sure you don't have a value of "12-2015" in the table? Worth a check, I think...

Comment: @Jon, sorry my mistake, there are value "12-2015" in table. I removed it and it is working fine now, thanks for your efforts.